# parsing a text file in php and retrieving information

Tags: php, regex, text-files

I'm trying to parse a basic text file in PHP, but not sure where to begin.

The file contains info such as:

http://pastebin.com/ahqtJzH6

You'll notice that the information I need to capture is split up by new lines. Right now I'm just throwing every new line into a $applicant[] array, but I need to get rid of the preceding text in each line.

I was thinking I probably need to use regex or something to single out just the data I need. Ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using regex, you can do this:

```
$fp = fopen('textfile.txt', 'r');

$return = array();
while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
   $parts = explode(':', $line);
   $key = trim($parts[0]);
   unset($parts[0]);
   $value = str_replace("\n", '', implode(':', $parts));
   $return[$key] = trim($value);
}

print_r($return);
```

Would output something like:

```
Array (
  [Applicant SSN]  => 123456789
  [Applicant Name] => BOB, BOB
  ...
)
```

Comment: I think it's best to use regex, because the file includes a lot of extraneous information aside from that that I have posted, that is formatted in a different way.

Comment: If all you want to do is capture the text that is past the colon, you don't need a regex. If things are more complicated, could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strpos` to find the : character and then grab everything after that. You can use `trim` to get rid of extra whitespace.

```
$lines = file('textfile.txt');

foreach ($lines as $line) {
   $p = strpos($line, ':');
   if ($p!==false) {
      $key = trim(substr($line, 0, $p));
      $value = trim(substr($line, $p+1));

      // do whatever with your key & value

   }
}
```